# Generalizations of Monogenic Fields

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

We recall that a number field $K$ is called *monogenic* if there exists some $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$ such that $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

If instead we take a tower of finite extensions $L-K-\mathbb{Q}$, it seems reasonable to call the extension $L/K$ *monogenic* if there exists some $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_L$ such that $\mathcal{O}_L = \mathcal{O}_K[\alpha]$.  In particular, this recovers our original definition when $K=\mathbb{Q}$.  Monogenic field extensions also have the property that the relative discriminant $\Delta_{L/K}$ is principal, generated by the discriminant of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K[t]$.

I've looked for references to this generalization without success, but would be grateful for one.  In particular, I'm looking for an example of a monogenic field extension $L/K$ such that $\Delta_{L/K} = \mathcal{O}_K$ (this last condition is equivalent to saying that no prime ideal in $K$ ramifies over $L$).   *Note: Minkowski's Theorem implies that this is impossible for $K = \mathbb{Q}$.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in Chapter 3 of Serre's Corps Locaux (Local fields) and also in Chapter 3.2 of Neukirch's Algebraic Number theory.